# Upload multiple Files in angular node multer

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload, multer, form-data

I am facing problem while uploading multiple files in angular, node, multer.
Last file in array is uploaded to server.

Here is my HTML.

```
<div class="mb-1">
    <p class="text-muted m-0">Anti Black List</p>
    <input type="file"  (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" name="Anti Black List" id="4" #fileDataAntiBlackList (onFileSelected)="onFileSelected($event ,fileDataAntiBlackList)" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader"  accept="application/pdf"/>  
  </div>
<div class="mb-1">
    <p class="text-muted m-0">Anti Black List</p>
    <input type="file"  (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" name="Shop Act" id="3" #fileDataShopAct (onFileSelected)="onFileSelected($event ,fileDataShopAct)" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader"  accept="application/pdf"/>  
  </div>
<div class="mb-1">
    <p class="text-muted m-0">Anti Black List</p>
    <input type="file"  (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" name="Professional Tax" id="2"  #fileDataPRO (onFileSelected)="onFileSelected($event ,fileDataPRO)" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader"  accept="application/pdf"/>  
  </div>
<div class="mb-1">
    <p class="text-muted m-0">Anti Black List</p>
    <input type="file"  (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" name="GST Copy" id="1" #fileDataGST (onFileSelected)="onFileSelected($event ,fileDataGST)" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader"  accept="application/pdf"/>  
  </div>
<mat-label>First name</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="f_name" matInput type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First name"  required/>
<mat-label>Last name</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="l_name" matInput type="text" name="Last_name" placeholder="Last name" required/>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="mx-4" (click)="onSubmit()"
        [disabled]="uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length && signupForm.invalid">Upload And Save </button>
```

There are more fields, but i have shown less here.

Following is TS file code

```
filesToUpload: Array<File> = [];
fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any) {
this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files;
//this.product.photo = fileInput.target.files[0]['name'];
}
onSubmit() {
//let files = this.getFiles();
let dbId: number;
let formData = new FormData();
const files: Array<File> = this.filesToUpload;
for(let i = 0; i < files.length;i++){
  formData.append("files", files[i], files[i]['name']);
}
formData.append('first_name',this.signupForm.value.f_name);
 this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/newUpload', formData)
    .map(files => files)
    .subscribe(files => console.log('files', files));
    return false;
}
```

This is my backend API
Upload

```
let user_storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, DIR);
},
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '' + path.extname(file.originalname));
}
});
let upload = multer({ storage: user_storage }).array('files',10);
```

API function

```
router.post('/newUpload',function(req,res){
console.log('before upload',req.body);
upload(req,res,function(err) {
    //console.log(req.body);
    //console.log(req.files);
    if(err) {
        return res.end("Error uploading file.");
    }
    console.log('files', req.files);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(req.files);
    //res.end("File is uploaded");
});
});
```

This is what i have tried. Only last file in array is save in uploads folder.
Also i want to insert first name , last name etc to database but when i console req.body is gives empty  json {}

**Edit quetion**
i got where i am missing.
Its in angular code : when i print

```
const files: Array<File> = this.filesToUpload;
```

i get last file which i uploaded. means it takes last file which is uploaded not all files.
so i use following function

```
getFiles(){
return this.uploader.queue.map((fileItem) => {
      return fileItem.file;
   });
}
```

So in onsubmit function

```
onSubmit() {
let files = this.getFiles();
let formData = new FormData();
for(let i = 0; i < files.length;i++){
  console.log(files[i]);
  formData.append("files", files[i],files[i]['name']);
}
```

When i console files[i], get all files.
But in line formData.append line i get following error

```
Argument of type 'FileLikeObject' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
Property 'slice' is missing in type 'FileLikeObject' but required in type 'Blob
```

P.S : when i send file name in formdata.append, i get all file names in node serevr.

Answer (score 1):

After trying different solutions,  finally i got working solutions by which multiple files and other input fields are also send to sever.

In my **Edit part** of question,  i have use following function

```
getFiles(){
return this.uploader.queue.map((fileItem) => {
  return fileItem.file;
});
}
```

above code was giving error. I have just changed return line.

**from**

```
return fileItem.file;
```

**to**

```
return fileItem.file.rawFile;
```

Thats it. All remaining code is same as in edit.

Answer (score 0):

you forget to add multer middleware to your router.post
it should be

```
outer.post('/newUpload',
    upload.array('myFiles', 12),
    function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err) {

   if(err) {
        return res.end("Error uploading file.");
    }
    res.send(req.files);
    //res.end("File is uploaded");
});
});
```

Comment: You can see in my code `let upload = multer({ storage: user_storage }).array('files',10);`  i have used array.
btw i have tried your code, still i am facing same problem. It uploads last file in array.

Comment: when you are appending to the form data try to do 
```
formData.append("files[]", files[i], files[i]['name']);
```
instead of 
```
formData.append("files", files[i], files[i]['name']);
```

Comment: you can read more about FormData usage here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: when i use `formData.append("files[]", files[i], files[i]['name']);`
i get error **MulterError: Unexpected field** 
this error occur because filed name and name in multer is diffrent